# Change MySQL representation of date

Tags: mysql, date, representation

Is there a way for me to change the representation of the output from this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Staff
```

Such that the `DOB` column, set as a Date datatype, will output `Tuesday, February, 1980`, as opposed to `1980-02-19`

Apologies if this has been asked before, but I'm struggling to find a Google search that yields the right results.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use: [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('1980-02-19', '%W, %M, %Y');
```